# Vmplayer 6.0.3 crashes on Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubuntu, vmware

Since updating to Kubuntu 14.04 vmplayer became unstable. I'm getting constant crashes like this:

```
*** Error in `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmplayer': malloc(): memory corruption:   0x00007fd306a36280 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

There are many situation it happens, but the most robust way to reproduce is to try to open virtual mashine properties. Crashes every time. Interestingly when VM is running after crash it's enough to play it again and it restores instantly (meaning that the VM is still working, just display went down).

Anyone experienced it ? Any solutions ?

Regards,
 Mkl

Comment: And you're sure you didn't change anything else about your system? You just updated Ubuntu? -- And from which version did you upgrade, and did you update VMPlayer as well?

Comment: vmware is a 3rd party app and hopefully someone will assist. You will have better luck with KVM (virt-manager). Virtualbox is also popular here, although it is also 3rd party.

Comment: I have the newest vmplayer available. And yes I updated it (from 6.0.1) after updating Kubuntu. Previous version of Kubuntu I was using were 12.10 (and there it was working fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by new gtkmm. Either vmplayer is using it incorrectly or there is a bug in gtkmm. VMplayer is prvoided with it's own (old) version of gtkmm . Making it use the old version solved the problem (in my case I just temporarily moved the system libraries and started vmware; since then it's using the old ones, even though I placed the system ones back on their place).